# .NET Core 3 automapper not mapping different name variables? Worked in .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Below is the Automapping profile. An error is thrown on the destination `Id` being of the wrong input format.

The destination `Id` property is not even being mapped to.

```
public class AspGetUserLoginReturnModelToSRSDLUserLoginModel : Profile
{
    public AspGetUserLoginReturnModelToSRSDLUserLoginModel()
    {
        CreateMap<asp_GetUserLoginReturnModel, SRSDLUserLoginModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UserPassword, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PasswordHash))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id)              
            ;
    }
}
```

Now the destination class `SRSDLUserLoginModel` is derived from a base class that has a public accessor named `Id` which is type of nullable `long`.

The source `Id` property used above is of type `string`.

As the code shown above the source `Id` is mapped to the destination `UserId` property.

But Automapper is mapping the source `Id` to the destination's based classes `Id` property.

WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?

The code is straight forward and there is nothing new trying to be accomplished.
It Automapper like most everything other packages that I have work with?

In the full/classic .NET framework, the packages worked fine, but in .NET Core those packages just suck?

```
// source class
public partial class asp_GetUserLoginReturnModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

// destination classes
public class SRSDLUserLoginModel: SRSDLModel, ISRSDLUserLoginModel
{  
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    //  [...]
}

public class SRSDLModel : ISRSDLModel
{  
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper will map properties with the same name by default so you don't have to write them all the time. In this case it tries to set the `SRSDLModel.Id` property with the value from the `asp_GetUserLoginReturnModel.Id` property. As you already noticed, that doesn't work because of the mismatch between `long?` and `string`.

To fix this, use the `.Ignore()` method in your mapping to specify that this specific property should no be set during mapping. The configuration might look like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, i => i.Ignore());
```